# How to give a server a static IP address with OpenWRT/LuCI?

Tags: domain-name-system, openwrt

I have an OpenWRT router and a small home network on 192.168.0.0/24. I have a server which has the static IP 192.168.0.10.

How can I set up an A record in OpenWRT/LuCI for it, to give it a DNS name? The OpenWRT UI has sections for static DHCP leases, but I don't want my server to use DHCP, just keep its static IPv4 addr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenWrt/LuCI you have also the option to set hostnames/dns. The following needs to be done:
Add Static lease in the `Network > DHCP and DNS` page in section `Static Leases`.

This will set both a hostname and static DHCP lease.